# trailing comma problem, javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently trying hard to get my jQuery to work in IE7, when I Lint the following:

```
$(".regflow").validate({
    errorLabelContainer: $("#error-message"),
    rules: {
        txtTextOnly: {required: true,textOnly: true},
        txtNumbersOnly: {required: true,numbersOnly: true},
        txtPhoneOnly: {required: true,phoneOnly: true},
        txtAreaCodeOnly: {required: true,numbersOnly: true},
        txtSimCodeOnly: {required: true,simCodeOnly: true},
        txtCprOnly1: {required: true,numbersOnly: true},
        txtCprOnly2: {required: true,cprOnly1: true},
        txtMailOnly: {required: true,mailOnly: true}
    },

    messages: {
        txtTextOnly: {required: "Dette felt skal udfyldes"},
        txtNumbersOnly: {required: "Dette felt skal udfyldes"},
        txtPhoneOnly: {required: "Dette felt skal udfyldes"},
        txtAreaCodeOnly: {required: "Dette felt skal udfyldes"},
        txtSimCodeOnly: {required: "Dette felt skal udfyldes"},
        txtCprOnly1: {required: "Dette felt skal udfyldes"},
        txtCprOnly2: {required: "Dette felt skal udfyldes"},
        txtMailOnly: {required: "Dette felt skal udfyldes"}
    },
});
```

... I get this error from Lint: *"warning: trailing comma is not legal in ECMA-262 object initializers"*

Does anyone know what this means, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Firefox will parse the code fine with or without the trailing comma, which is misleading. Internet Explorer 7/8 (and probably below) does not.

Comment: This is one case when IE keeps to the standard but Firebox does not!

Comment: Firefox would give you a strict warning, but that will no longer happen in Firefox 3.6 since this is allowed behavior in ES5.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove the trailing comma - the comma at the end of the following part:

```
 messages: {
        txtTextOnly: {required: "Dette felt skal udfyldes"},
        txtNumbersOnly: {required: "Dette felt skal udfyldes"},
        txtPhoneOnly: {required: "Dette felt skal udfyldes"},
        txtAreaCodeOnly: {required: "Dette felt skal udfyldes"},
        txtSimCodeOnly: {required: "Dette felt skal udfyldes"},
        txtCprOnly1: {required: "Dette felt skal udfyldes"},
        txtCprOnly2: {required: "Dette felt skal udfyldes"},
        txtMailOnly: {required: "Dette felt skal udfyldes"}
    },
```

While creating an object `{}` or an array `[]`, you separate individual elements with a comma. But here there is an additional comma after the last item like `[a, b, c,]` - that is not allowed as per ECMA-262.

Comment: Firefox would actually give you a strict warning about this, but note that this behavior has changed in ES5.  See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=508637 for more details.

Answer (score 6):

The extra comma near the bottom:

```
$(".regflow").validate({
    errorLabelContainer: $("#error-message"),
    rules: {
        txtTextOnly: {required: true,textOnly: true},
        txtNumbersOnly: {required: true,numbersOnly: true},
        txtPhoneOnly: {required: true,phoneOnly: true},
        txtAreaCodeOnly: {required: true,numbersOnly: true},
        txtSimCodeOnly: {required: true,simCodeOnly: true},
        txtCprOnly1: {required: true,numbersOnly: true},
        txtCprOnly2: {required: true,cprOnly1: true},
        txtMailOnly: {required: true,mailOnly: true}
    },

    messages: {
        txtTextOnly: {required: "Dette felt skal udfyldes"},
        txtNumbersOnly: {required: "Dette felt skal udfyldes"},
        txtPhoneOnly: {required: "Dette felt skal udfyldes"},
        txtAreaCodeOnly: {required: "Dette felt skal udfyldes"},
        txtSimCodeOnly: {required: "Dette felt skal udfyldes"},
        txtCprOnly1: {required: "Dette felt skal udfyldes"},
        txtCprOnly2: {required: "Dette felt skal udfyldes"},
        txtMailOnly: {required: "Dette felt skal udfyldes"}
    }, //<--- this one!!!!
});
```

Comment: Thx a bunch, a n00b mistake, i know :)

Answer (score 3):

Is it not talking about:

```
    }, // This comma here?
});
```

on the second to last line?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the last comma from the second last line:

```
$(".regflow").validate({
    errorLabelContainer: $("#error-message"),
    rules: {
        txtTextOnly: {required: true,textOnly: true},
        txtNumbersOnly: {required: true,numbersOnly: true},
        txtPhoneOnly: {required: true,phoneOnly: true},
        txtAreaCodeOnly: {required: true,numbersOnly: true},
        txtSimCodeOnly: {required: true,simCodeOnly: true},
        txtCprOnly1: {required: true,numbersOnly: true},
        txtCprOnly2: {required: true,cprOnly1: true},
        txtMailOnly: {required: true,mailOnly: true}
    },

    messages: {
        txtTextOnly: {required: "Dette felt skal udfyldes"},
        txtNumbersOnly: {required: "Dette felt skal udfyldes"},
        txtPhoneOnly: {required: "Dette felt skal udfyldes"},
        txtAreaCodeOnly: {required: "Dette felt skal udfyldes"},
        txtSimCodeOnly: {required: "Dette felt skal udfyldes"},
        txtCprOnly1: {required: "Dette felt skal udfyldes"},
        txtCprOnly2: {required: "Dette felt skal udfyldes"},
        txtMailOnly: {required: "Dette felt skal udfyldes"}
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked a while ago, but this might be helpful. If you run your JavaScript through [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) it will tell you if there are any of these "extra commas."