# JQuery Uploadify not not showing in IE7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins

I am using Uploadify http://www.uploadify.com/
in my asp.net mvc application however it works great but when using IE7 it doesn't show up I am hoping someone has some insight as to how to fix this. I did look through thier forums and there are several problems in IE7 posted but nothing related to what my problem is and with a solution.

**Edit:** This is what my code looks like, this works fine in IE8,Firefox and Safari but in IE7 uploadify doesn't show the image, that replaces the File Upload Input DOM element.

```
$("#uploadify").uploadify({
                'uploader': '/content/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
                'script': '/user/uploader',
                'buttonImg': '/content/images/brown/file_upload.png',
                'folder': '/assets',
                'width': 208,
                'height': 30,
                'wmode': 'transparent',
                'cancelImg': '/content/uploadify/cancel.png',
                'auto': true,
                'onComplete': function(event, queueID, fileObj, data) {
                 $("#profile_image").load('/user/preview');
                }
            });
```

Comment: Maybe you could provide what you've tried so far, what do you expect to get from it and the actual result you are getting (any source code isolating the problem would be appreciated).

Comment: To avoid the obvious: did the particular IE7 have flash installed?

Comment: To extend on BalusC's question: Does IE7 have flash 10 installed?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same symptoms as you (i.e. working everywhere except IE7). The reason was [a trailing comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819821/trailing-comma-problem-javascript) at the end of my uploadify configuration, so even though this will not solve your problem it may help someone else.